# Hidden text area taking up space

Tags: jquery, html

So I have the following code setup so that when and only when a user checks     Other, then the "If other box" shows. Doing so leaves empty space when the box is hidden. Is there anyway to get rid of this when the box is unchecked and scroll the content down and add the "If other box" when the Other box is checked.

Here is the following working code

```js
    $('#other').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.otherCon').css('visibility', 'visible');
      } else {
        $('.otherCon').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }
    });
```

```css
.otherCon {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="userCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="Other" value="Other" />
    <label>Other</label>
  </div>
  <div class="otherCon">
    <label>If other</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="Other Response"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>More info</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="More info"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just use `.hide()` and `.show()`?!

Comment: visibility basically just makes things "transparent". The thing still occupies space, it still counts for sizing/positioning calculations. It's just simply completely see-through. If you want it ELIMINATED from positioning/sizing calculations, then use `display: none` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibility` and `opacity` are just making the elements *transparent* but don't let them disappear. For this you will need `display` set to `none`. Or even better, as you are using jQuery, [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```
$('#other').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.otherCon').show();
    } else {
        $('.otherCon').hide();
    }
});
```

Or, because you use a condition, just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('#other').on('click', function() {
    $('.otherCon').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Working example:

```js
$('#other').on('click', function() {
    $('.otherCon').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.otherCon {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="userCheck">
  <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="Other" value="Other" />
  <label>Other</label>
</div>
<div class="otherCon">
  <label>If other</label>
  <textarea id="text" name="Other Response"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <label>More info</label>
  <textarea id="text" name="More info"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display: none` instead. That hides the element and doesn't any space. jQuery has functions hide(), show() and toggle() to make it easier

Answer (score -1):

You can use the attribute `hidden` for the `div` with class `otherCon` and change the jquery to use `show()` or `hide()` or remove the `if` and add `$('.otherCon').toggle();`

```js
    $('#other').on('click', function() {
      //$('.otherCon').toggle();
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.otherCon').show();
      } else {
        $('.otherCon').hide();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="userCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="Other" value="Other" />
    <label>Other</label>
  </div>
  <div class="otherCon" hidden>
    <label>If other</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="Other Response"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>More info</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="More info"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

when setting the `visibility`, the element is just 'invisible' but still takes space to place it, you may want to use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`, `slideUp` and `slideDown` of the jQuery that will really hide the element and also get rid of their spaces with animation. You could also change the `display` property to `none` or `block` to hide it in a simply way

```
$('#other').on('click', function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('.otherCon').slideDown();
 } else {
   $('.otherCon').slideUp();
 }
});
```

You could also use the `<label for="checkbox id"/>` to toggle the `checked` state of checkbox by click on the label text

try it on https://jsfiddle.net/8qqLmyad/1/

Comment: `style="display:none"`

Comment: You may append a css style to the `div` that indicate `display: none;`, see the example on https://jsfiddle.net/8qqLmyad/2/